# ASP.NET Repeater: Button in item template to redirect to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater and each item contains a button which should redirect to another page and also pass a value in the query string.

I am not getting any errors, but when I click the button, the page just refreshes (so I am assuming a `postback` **does** occur) and does not redirect. I think that for some reason, it isn't recognizing the `CommandName` of the button.

Repeater code:

---

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MySponsoredChildrenList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="MySponsoredChildrenList_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="MySponsoredChildrenList_ItemCommand">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <br />
        <div id="OuterDiv">
            <div id="InnerLeft">
                <asp:Image ID="ProfilePic" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"~/Resources/Children Images/" + String.Format("{0}", Eval("Primary_Image")) %>'
                    Width='300px' Style="max-height: 500px" /></div>
            <div id="InnerRight">
            <asp:HiddenField ID="ChildID" runat="server" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Child_ID") %>'/>   
                    <span style="font-size: 20px; font-weight:bold;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Surname") %></span>
                <br /><br /><br />

                What have you been up to?
                <br /><br />
                    <span style="font-style:italic">"<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MostRecentUpdate")%>"</span>    

                    <span style="font-weight:bold"> -<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Update_Date", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")%></span><br /><br /><br />Sponsored till:

                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "End_Date", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")%>
                <br /><br />

                <asp:Button ID="ChildProfileButton" runat="server" Text="View Profile"  CommandName="ViewProfile"  />
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        <div id="SeparatorDiv">
        </div>
    </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

C# Code behind:

---

```
protected void MySponsoredChildrenList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
            {
                // Stuff to databind
                Button myButton = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("ChildProfileButton");

                myButton.CommandName = "ViewProfile";                }
        }

        protected void MySponsoredChildrenList_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "ViewProfile")
            {
                int ChildIDQuery = Convert.ToInt32(e.Item.FindControl("ChildID"));
                Response.Redirect("~/ChildDescription.aspx?ID=" + ChildIDQuery);
            }

        }
```

I am new to using repeaters so it's probably just a rookie mistake. On a side note: is there a better way of obtaining the ChildID without using a hidden field?

EDIT: Using breakpoints; the ItemDatabound event handler is being hit, but the ItemCommand is not being entered at all

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint at the start of the event handler? Does it get hit? What does `e.CommandName` evaluate to?

Comment: Are You getting any error while Clicking.

Comment: Just tried it, none of the event handlers seem to be getting called. Adding the onClick attribute to the button for either of the events results in an error when I load the page.

@Black_Crown: no error when clicking, the page seems to postback and refreshes

Comment: Its has to Show Some Error.Have you Tried FireBug in Browser.??

Comment: Where have you registered the `ItemCommand` event handler?

Comment: I added the OnItemCommand to the repeater but it still just refreshes the page, when I also add OnItemDataBound I get an error, let my edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set MySponsoredChildrenList_ItemDataBound as protected. Right now, you have just 'void' which by default is private, and is not accessible to the front aspx page.

Another way is to use the add event handler syntax from a function in your code behind, using the += operator.

Either way, the breakpoint will now be hit and our code should mwork.

**EDIT: So the above solved the compilation error but the breakpoints are not being hit; I've ran some tests and am able to hit breakpoints like this:**

Since I do not know how you are databinding, I just added this code to my code-behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            MySponsoredChildrenList.DataSource = new List<object>() { null };
            MySponsoredChildrenList.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Note: If you DataBind() and ItemDataBound() is called on every postback, it will wipe out the command argument, which is potentially what you are seeeing; so if you always see [object]_ItemDataBound() breakpoint hit, but never [object]_ItemCommand(), it is because you need to databind only on the initial page load, or after any major changes are made.

Note also the method MySponsoredChildrenList_ItemCommand doesn't work:

```
    protected void MySponsoredChildrenList_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "ViewProfile")
        {
            int ChildIDQuery = Convert.ToInt32(e.Item.FindControl("ChildID"));
            Response.Redirect("~/ChildDescription.aspx?ID=" + ChildIDQuery);
        }

    }
```

When you do FindControl, you need to cast to the correct control type, and also make sure to check for empty and null values before converting, or else you will possibly have errors:

```
    protected void MySponsoredChildrenList_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "ViewProfile")
        {
            int childId = 0;
            var hiddenField = e.Item.FindControl("ChildID") as HiddenField;
            if (null != hiddenField)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hiddenField.Value))
                {
                    childId = Convert.ToInt32(hiddenField.Value);
                }
            }

            if (childId > 0)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/ChildDescription.aspx?ID=" + childId);
            }
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps - if not, please post additional code for the "full picture" of what is happening, so we can see where else you might have a problem.

Comment: This solved the compilation error, but the breakpoints still aren't being hit :/ thanks for your help so far +1 for solving compilation error

EDIT: The itemDataBound is being hit, but the itemCommand is not

Comment: You have not posted the code where you DataBind() the repeater; I've just passed this to my own application and added some code to databind to a dummy, and it works. Also you have errors in the MySponsoredChildrenList_ItemCommand method.

Comment: See my expended answer which explains why ItemDataBound is always hit and ItemComment is not ever hit - you are most likely data binding on every postback, and wiping out the command arguments. Try databinding only on initial page load (see my edit for details).

Comment: I chose your answer instead because it goes into more detail and will help other people with the same problem more. Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I *think* on the repeater you need to add

OnItemDataBound="MySponsoredChildrenList_ItemDataBound"

Not 100% sure, but could be the same for the ItemCommand.

--

In regards to obtaining the ChildID. Add a `CommandArgument` to the button in the repeater, and set it in the same way, `<% Eval("ChildID") %>`. This can the be obtained using `e.CommandArgument`.

Comment: Just tried this, but it gives me a compilation error (see edit in question)

Comment: Might sound obvious, but when you say "code behind", you mean the mysponsoredchildren.aspx.cs file, not a class file in the App_Code folder? Shouldn't make any difference, but in your example, that ItemDataBound is just void, not protected. Just fishing for things to check here.... :)

Comment: I changed it to protected and that solved the compilation error I was getting but still just does postback and refreshes the page :/ thanks for your help so far

Comment: Where are you binding the repeater? If it's rebinding to the datasource on each postback, you'd lose whatever the button would be doing. You need to add `if (!IsPostback)` in the `Page_Load`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. Add an attribute to item row

```
row.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("window.location = '{0}';", ResolveClientUrl(string.Format("~/YourPage.aspx?userId={0}", e.Item.DataItem)) );
```

or You can do like this also

```
<ItemTemplate>      <tr onmouseover="window.document.title = '<%# Eval("userId", "Click to navigate onto user {0} details page.") %>'"          onclick='window.location = "<%# ResolveClientUrl( "~/YourPage.aspx?userId=" + Eval("userid") ) %>"'>           <td>                <%# Eval("UserId") %>           </td>      </tr> </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Where exactly do I put this? I am sorry but I am very new to asp in general, thanks for your help.